# Unknown exception while deserializing using simple XML

Tags: java, exception, serialization, simple-framework

I am deserializing data using Simple XML in Java, but i get an exception telling me:

```
protokolsimulering.model.Terminal.<init>()
```

This is my serializing code:

```
public void saveSimulationState(String simulationFile) {
    try{
        Strategy strategy = new CycleStrategy("id", "ref");
        Serializer serializer = new Persister(strategy);
        File result = new File(simulationFile);
        serializer.write(this.sm, result);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}

public void loadSimulationState(String simulationFile) {
    try {
        Strategy strategy = new CycleStrategy("id", "ref");
        Serializer serializer = new Persister(strategy);
        File source = new File(simulationFile);
        this.sm = serializer.read(Simulation.class, source);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

The code for Terminal.java is:

```
package protokolsimulering.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import protokolsimulering.model.DataPacket.*;

public class Terminal extends Sensor {

    public Terminal(int x, int y, double r) {
        super(x,y,r);
        learnPosition();
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        this.broadcast(PacketFactory.newRutePacket(this,0));
    }

    @Override
    public void step() {
        ArrayList<AbstractPacket> packetsThisStep = (ArrayList<AbstractPacket>) this.getPackages();

        for(AbstractPacket p : packetsThisStep) {
            if(p instanceof HalloPacket) {    
                // Rutningsprotokol
                send(p.getSender(),PacketFactory.newRutePacket(this,0));

                // Lokaliseringsprotokol
                send(p.getSender(), PacketFactory.newHerPacket(this, this.getKnownPosition()));
        }
    }
}
```

}

The entire source code can be found at:

http://code.google.com/p/sensor-protocol-simulation/source/browse/#svn/trunk/src/protokolsimulering

Comment: Posting the stacktrace might help

Comment: Note that it is failing in <init> not init() i.e. the problem is in the constructor

Comment: The stacktrace is:

null
protokolsimulering.model.Terminal.<init>()
debug:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 17 seconds)


And the code making this is:

catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getCause());
            System.out.println(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

Answer (score 1):

The exception means the problem is related to invoking the Terminal constructor.

Typically, to construct objects when deserializing, a no-args contructor must be available, like this:

```
public Terminal() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, while the OP's question is very vague and leaves out most useful information, it's clear that something is looking for a no-arg constructor for Terminal.

Comment: I fixed this by adding a constructor to Terminal, but now the error seems to be:

protokolsimulering.model.DataPacket$HalloPacket.<init>()

Which i tried to solve using the same method, only this did not do the trick.

Comment: Without more details, it's hard to say, but you might make sure you added an empty constructor to HalloPacket (the error is on an inner class, not on DataPacket)

Comment: I added the empty constructor to all classes related to DataPacket (also HalloPacket). I can post all needed details here, just not sure what would be relevant. I have posted a link to the complete source code and the exception i am getting.

Comment: protokolsimulering.model.DataPacket$HalloPacket is clearly a non-static inner, make it a static inner and it will work.